# Derivation for a mixed distribution, Poisson Lindley

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, marginal-distribution

I want to derive the Poisson Lindley Distribution.

$$ f_x(x|\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}e^{-\lambda}$$
$$f_x(x|p) = \frac{p^2}{(p+1)}(\lambda+1)e^{-\lambda p}$$

The Distribution of x, $f_x(x) = \int ^\infty _0 f_x(x|\lambda) f_\lambda(\lambda) \ d\lambda$

Then $$ f_x(x) = \frac{p^2}{(p+1)(x-1)!}\int ^\infty _0 \lambda^{x-1}(\lambda+1) e^{-\lambda(1+p)} \ d\lambda$$

I broke it as sum of 2 integrals:

$$ f_x(x) = \frac{p^2}{(p+1)(x-1)!}\left [\int ^\infty _0 \lambda^xe^{-\lambda(1+p)} \ d\lambda \ +\int ^\infty _0 \lambda^{x-1}e^{-\lambda(1+p)} \ d\lambda  \right] $$

As I solve $\int ^\infty _0 \lambda^xe^{-\lambda(1+p)} \ d\lambda = \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda(1+p)}}{-(1+p)} +\frac{1}{1+p} \int ^\infty _0 \lambda^{x-1}e^{-\lambda(1+p)} \ d\lambda $

Then rewriting $f_x(x):$
$$f_x(x) = \frac{p^2}{(p+1)(x-1)!} \int ^\infty _0 \frac{p+2}{p+1} \lambda^{x-1} e^{-\lambda(1+p)} \ d\lambda$$

I am unable to proceed further to show that the Poisson-Lindley distribution is:

$$\frac{p^2}{(p+1)^{x+3}}(p+2+x)$$